# User.IsInRole is not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using ASP.NET 2012, SQL Server 2008 and C# for my website. When I execute the following code:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
```

In the `Default.aspx.cs` and ran in Visual Studio locally there is no error. After deploying my website and attempting to login with a user that is in the `Admin Role` the following error on the server:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

My ASP.NET membership database is located on host. Should I use connection string in `Default.aspx.cs`? If yes, how can I write for this purpose?

I am sure that the `User` that I log in with with is in the `Admin Role`.

`web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MembersConnectionString" 
         connectionString="workstation id=mssql;packet size=4096;user id=shahi_SQLLogin_1;pwd=password;data source=mssql;persist security info=False;initial catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="SabteAKhabar" 
         connectionString="workstation id=mssql;packet size=4096;user id=shahi_SQLLogin_1;pwd=password;data source=mssql;persist security info=False;initial catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="workstation id=mssql;packet size=4096;user id=shahi_SQLLogin_1;pwd=password;data source=mssql;persist security info=False;initial catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="akhbarrConnectionString" 
         connectionString="workstation id=mssql;packet size=4096;user id=shahi_SQLLogin_1;pwd=password;data source=mssql;persist security info=False;initial catalog=akhbarrr"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="access.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="nofile.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="LastName" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="AkharinMadrak" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="Reshte" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="Gerayesh" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="NahveAshnayi" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="Address" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="PostalKod" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="City" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="Town" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="Number" allowAnonymous="false"/>
        <add name="BirthDay" type="System.DateTime" allowAnonymous="false"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Managers"/>
      <allow roles="Admin"/>
      <allow roles="AdminAsli"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="5" cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="MembersConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplication" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <machineKey validationKey="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890AAAAAAAAAA" decryptionKey="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MSCaptcha" path="CaptchaImage.axd" verb="GET" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xxxxxx@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="xxxxxx" port="587" userName="farzanehsd@gmail.com" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Poorly worded and shows a basic lack of understanding

Comment: Your membership connection string points to the `akhbarrr` database - did you install the necessary database tables and stored procedures for the ASP.NET membership system in that database? The default setup would be to have a separate membership and role database called `ASPNETDB` in your system

Comment: the ASPNETDB was created by asp.net membership wizard and I just create a database akhbarrr in host and copy the aspnetdb script in akhbarr database. then I fill table with my Users And Roles and other datas. now I can Login and register with this database but for role detect there is some error @marc_s

Comment: OMG! you right! the problem solved after adding rolemanager tag and it's codes!Im so thank you for your huge help!

Comment: @marc_s: I have to rewrite your answer as Answer Your Question or I can waiting you to write this answer and then mark it as answer?

Comment: @littleengineer: turned my comment into an answer now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined all the details necessary for the membership provider - but nothing for the **role provider**!

```
<!-- you're providing all the details for the membership provider ...... -->
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
   <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="MembersConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplication" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
</membership>

<!-- but nothing at all really for the role provider. -->
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
```

[See this blog post by Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/articles/428.aspx) on how to define the role providers details, define where to find the information and what role provider to use - and do the same as you did for membership for the role provider, too!

Answer (score 1):

There is no error with your C# code as the error message is clearly telling you.

There is an error connecting to your database which is mostly likely caused by missing or incorrect entries in your configuration file.

**Sample configuration:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MembersConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=akhbarrr.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;persist security info=False;Initial Catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="SabteAKhabar" 
        connectionString="Data Source=akhbarrr.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;persist security info=False;Initial Catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=akhbarrr.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;persist security info=False;Initial Catalog=akhbarrr" />
    <add name="akhbarrConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=akhbarrr.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;User Id=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;persist security info=False;Initial Catalog=akhbarrr"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Reference / Further Reading:**
For more information on the configuration side of ASP.NET membership please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx

### Alternative Answer

As your membership application name is called `MyApplication`. Can you make sure that the `ApplicationId` value in your `aspnet_Applications` database table matches the values in your `aspnet_Roles` tables for your roles.

In the `aspnet_Roles` table you will find a list of current ASP.NET membership roles. Can you make sure that your role exists there and that the ApplicationId value matches the one from your `aspnet_Applications` table.

You can run this query to see what roles you have set up and against what ASP.NET Membership application:

```
SELECT APP.ApplicationId, APP.ApplicationName, ROLES.RoleName, ROLES.RoleId 
FROM dbo.aspnet_Applications AS APP
JOIN dbo.aspnet_Roles AS ROLES ON APP.ApplicationId = ROLES.ApplicationId
```

Comment: thanks but my webconfig has no problem when I check with your Code. I can login and resister in m website but when I use User.IsInRole the SQL server error occurs.

Comment: You need to post your config as that is the error you are telling us you are getting.

Comment: I wrote the Webconfig File in my Question now

Comment: I have updated my `connectionString` part of my answer. Can you place this in your config (remember to change the `User Id` and `Password` values to your correct ones).

Comment: There is no change in error after replace your code in my config file.

Comment: I have updated my answer and I am sure I know what your problem was.

Comment: but after checking tables I discovered that the applicationId for this role is equal with applicationId for myapplication

Comment: @littleengineer See the updated query. Can you run this and tell me what you get. All of your `ApplicationName` rows should say `MyApplication` if they do not then there is a problem.

Comment: so thanks for your attention. but  the problem solved after adding rolemanager tag and it's codes in webconfig file

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the user or the role. The error message is telling you what's wrong and what to do: your program cannot access your SQL database, so you need to check that it's set up properly. Specifically, check that:

- your SQL server is running
- your SQL server is set to accept connections from the program
- your program has the correct connection string in the `Web.config` file

Comment: If my connection string was wrong I was unable to Login/Register too. but the problem in only on the page that on code behind I wrote User.IsInRole